PyWinRm credentials getting rejected from doing windows to windows connection
I am using PyWinRm on my windows machine to connect to a remote host using Kerberos. In our environment we use pywinrm on our linux machines to run PowerShell commands all the time using Kerberos. The issue im running into is when i try to run a simple command like: "echo test" it gives me an error of "the specified credentials were rejected by the server". I have winrm configured to support remote PowerShell and have gotten it to work with ntlm but not Kerberos.
Kerberos = true
Negotiate = true
certificate = true
cbthardeninglevel = Relaxed

import winrm
S = winrm.Session("ComputerName", auth=("UserName", None), 
transport="kerberos")
r = s.run_ps('ipconfig')
print(r.std_out)

i tried changing the host name to http://ComputerName:5985/wsman but i still get the error of credentials were rejected.
i have winkerberos installed but i dont know how or if i need to implement it here. i added kerberos_delegation=True to the session command and still get a credential error. Kerberos does work on my machine because i used anther library called ms_active_directory that uses Kerberos and it works.

Is your "ComputerName" correct? Does it match the machine account name in AD? Does running the script with KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr show it trying to obtain the correct ticket?

so after doing some digging the only listener we have on our system is HTTP. i created a new listener with https and it works. I figured out its because of Basic is set to false on our network. is it possible to use http without having basic set to true?

Hold on a moment – Basic auth? Where did that come from? You were trying to use Kerberos, which is as far away from Basic as it gets... And so is HTTP for that matter: last I checked, you can't actually use WinRM over http with Basic; it only accepts Kerberos and NTLM in the first place.

oh? so is there any reason why it would work over https but not http?

Good question. Does running the script with KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr show it trying to obtain the correct ticket? (Or any ticket at all?)

im running this on a windows machine and from what im reading online that's for linux right?

Right, as you mentioned using pywinrm from Linux. There's no direct equivalent for Windows but Wireshark might show the Kerberos requests (unless FAST is in use ...) Alternatively, can you try python-pypsrp instead of pywinrm?

after running
winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener 
i only had a listener for http running. seeing that the config basic = True is unsecure i create a new listener with the command:
winrm quickconfig -transport:https
once this was completed kerberos was able to communicate after changing the host name to: https://ComputerName:5986/wsman

If this is the case, are you sure you are using Kerberos? Basic auth is explicitly not Kerberos!

yes, i verified with security logs and with our security team, for some reason pywinrm needs @basic turned on in order for http to work.

How did you verify it? What kind of Authorization header does it send?
